# Get rid of unnecessary class in variadic template recursion base case

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

The following variadic template recursively creates classes and adds each of the specified members in sequence:

```
class Dummy {};

template<class Base, typename... Members>
// using Composition = Base;
class Composition : public Base {};

template<class Base, typename FirstMember, typename... MoreMembers>
class Composition<Base, FirstMember, MoreMembers...>
    : public Composition<Base, MoreMembers...> {
protected:
    FirstMember member;
};

Composition<Composition<
    Composition<Dummy, int>, Composition<Dummy, int>*>, double> composition;
```

It works, but I feel the terminating step is a bit clumsy: It creates a new class `Composition<Base>` which inherits from `Base` but does not do anything else. I would prefer if the last step could simply be `template<class Base, typename... Members> using Composition = Base;` - but that is not allowed because we may not specialize alias templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just get tid of `Dummy` altogether and make the 1-argument form the stop condition:

```
template<typename... Members>
class Composition;

template<typename FirstMember, typename... MoreMembers>
class Composition<FirstMember, MoreMembers...>
    : public Composition<MoreMembers...> {
protected:
    FirstMember member;
};

template<typename FirstMember>
class Composition<FirstMember>
{
protected:
    FirstMember member;
};

Composition<Composition<
    Composition<int>, Composition<int>*>, double> composition;
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/acd594fe43341c5d)

If, as clarified in comments, `Base` is an important part of the design, you should be able to achieve what you want by adding one more layer of indirection:

```
template <class Base, class... Members>
struct CompositionHelper;

template <class Base, class... Members>
using Composition = typename CompositionHelper<Base, Members...>::Type;

template <class Base>
struct CompositionHelper<Base>
{
  using Type = Base;
};

template <class Base, class FirstMember, class... MoreMembers>
struct CompositionHelper<Base, FirstMember, MoreMembers...>
{
  class Type : public Composition<Base, MoreMembers...>
  {
  protected:
    FirstMember member;
  };
};

Composition<Composition<
    Composition<Dummy, int>, Composition<Dummy, int>*>, double> composition;
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e181f6d7bbca8630)

Comment: Well this gets rid of `Base`, and that is not what I want. I want `Composition<Base>` to be an alias (or as close to that as possible) for `Base`, instead of a class that extends `Base`.

Comment: @not-a-user That's not really visible from the question at all, you might want to edit it. I will try to provide a solution in the meantime.

Comment: @not-a-user - but what about `Composition<int, long>`? If `Composition<int>` is an alias for `int`, you have `Composition<int, long> : public int`; and this is forbidden.

Comment: @max66 First argument must be an extendable class, yes.